# Scanner noSuchElementException. What is the cause of it? How can i fix it?

Tags: java, exception, nosuchelementexception

```
            Scanner newName = new Scanner(System.in);  //creating scanner object
            System.out.println("Δωστε ονομα : ");
            String getOnoma = newName.nextLine(); /*throws no such element exception at String getOnoma=newName.nextLine*/
            newName.close();
```

I don't know how to fix the exception, i think this is the first time i use scanner in Java

Comment: there's nothing wrong with that code, and it doesn't throw any Exceptions. Are you sure you saved/rebuild your code before running?

Comment: Can you provide the whole stack-trace and information about how you ran this program

Comment: Agreed with @Stultuske, I can't get your code to throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

You're calling nextLine() and it's throwing an exception when there's no line, exactly as the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) describes. It will never return null

Use a check

```
if(newName.hasNextLine()) {
  String getOnoma = newName.nextLine();
}
```

For whatever reason, the Scanner class also issues this same exception if it encounters special characters it cannot read. Beyond using the hasNextLine() method before each call to nextLine(), make sure the correct encoding is passed to the Scanner constructor, e.g.:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: with the input being manual, how would that even be possible?